# Are there render layers in Blender 2.9?

Tags: objects, interface

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/gPW4MrBx1nk) to put portals in Blender for a project I'm working on. Everything was going smoothly until I got to 9:33 in the video, where I have to set render layers for specific objects. The shortcut listed in the video is M, and should pull up this context menu:
[image: Render Layers context menu]
But in 2.9, M pulls up this context menu:
[image: Add to Groups context menu]
I searched through all of the Properties menus and windows, and the closest I could find was the *View* Layers, but I didn't think that was correct. Are the View Layers correct? Did the developers just completely remove the Render Layers feature entirely? If both of those are false, where can I find the render layers?

Comment: View Layers have not replaced the former layers. Former Layers are now replaced by the Collections, which work differently (not so complicated though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old *layers* and the "new" *collections* essentially work the same way. It's a way to organize your scene, and toggle each layer on/off, nothing more. *Collections* are much more useful though, as you can clearly see them in your outliner, and toggle many properties of it, like viewport- and render display, holdout, selectability, etc, which apply to all items in that *collection*.

You can read all about *collections* here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html

Comment: *Objects* can also exist in more than one *Collection* at the same time